# Is there a way to print Flask data back to React Front-end?

Tags: python, reactjs, flask

I have a React web-app running that sends data to a Flask back-end via a POST request. The back-end processes the data and needs to return the results back to the front-end. How do I print my results on the React front-end?
Here is my Flask code :

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, send_from_directory
from flask_cors import CORS
import sys
import escode

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

@app.route('/result', methods = ['GET','POST'])

def result():
    SearchData = request.get_json()

    results = escode.retrieve_results( SearchData['MaskList'][0]['SpecChar'] )
    data = [doc for doc in results['hits']['hits']]
    for doc in data:
        print("(%s) %s"% (doc['_id'], doc['_source']['Name']), file=sys.stderr)

    return jsonify({ 'msg' : 'hi hello' }), 200

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can capture the data using `useState` of react by declaring:

```
const[getMessage,setMessage] = useState('');
```

Then pass the result to `setMessage(response)` in your API call which was returned by Flask and, finally, you can use `getMessage` in your HTML tags something like this:

```
<div>{getMessage}</div>
```

Comment: Can you please explain in detail? I can share my React code if it's necessary.

Comment: Can you create a codepen or js fiddle so that i can take a look at your react code.